# Process a stream of events after a Start event and return to listen when an End event occurs

Tags: rxjs

The scenario I am working on is composed by 3 Observables.

**StartObs**: this Observable emits when I need to start a sequence of processings - the data emitted is a ***processID*** of the process I need to fulfill

**DoStuffObs**: this Observable emits ***commands*** upon which I have to do something - I want to start listening to such Observable just after **StartObs** has emitted and I need the ***processID*** of the process to perform my duties with the function `doTheWork(command, processId)`

**EndObs**: this Observable emits when I have to end the processing of a certain ***processID*** and have to go back to listen to the next emission of **StartObs**

So basically is: *Start*, *DoStuff* until *End* and then go back to listening to the next *Start*.

It is also guaranteed that after one *Start* comes sooner or later one *End* and that it is not possible to have 2 *Start* without an *End* in between or 2 *End* without a *Start in* between.

The first 2 steps can be achieved via `switchMap`, like

```
StartObs
.switchMap(processId => DoStuff.map(command => ({command, processId})))
.tap(data => doTheWork(data.command, data.processId))
```

What is not clear to me is how to deal with **EndObs**.

The option of using `takeUntil` does not work, since I do not want to complete the chain started with **StartObs** since I have to go back to listening for the next process to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I think `takeUntil()` is the best choice here in combination with `repeat()`.

```
StartObs
  .switchMap(processId => DoStuff.map(command => ({command, processId})))
  .tap(data => doTheWork(data.command, data.processId))
  .takeUntil(EndObs)
  .repeat();
```

When the chain completes with `takeUntil()` it will immediately resubscribe thanks to `repeat()` and the whole process will start all over again.